# The electron–cyclotron maser emissions from Earth

Tags: earth, exoplanet, jupiter, radio

The first-ever detection of radio signals caused by the electron–cyclotron maser mechanism outside of the Solar System, on Tau Bootis b was recently published ([here](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/forth/aa37201-19.pdf)). This phenomenon causes huge radio emissions from Jupiter, for example, due to the enormous amount of plasma ions from Io. On Earth, I suppose, this phenomenon still happens, due to the plasma radiation of the Sun on Earth ionosphere.

My question is: how strong is it and how it's compared to Tau Bootis and Jupiter?